# Oracle: Update tree trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Lets say I have a table with an `ID` and a `PARENT_ID`.

I want to create an "on update" trigger, so whenever `ID` is updated, any `PARENT_ID` which pointed to that `ID` is also updated.

The main issue I can see with this however is that I don't think Oracle allows you to select from a table which a trigger is currently executing on.

I know I could just wrap the "update" code in a PL/SQL function, but I have users which are probably more comfortable manipulating this data with just SQL.

What's the best way to achieve what I'm after without forcing the user to call to much PL/SQL (I'm happy to implement it with PL/SQL obviously, as long as it's fairly transparent to the user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up achieving this by basing a view on the table and then making the view updatable by using an `instead of` trigger. This instead of trigger did the appropriate updates to the `id`s and `parent_id`s in the base table.

Answer (score 1):

even PL/SQL nested into a trigger will cause a mutation here.

it sounds like a normalization issue.  why would you need to update another row?  i would suggest looking at that value that you are maintaining, and move it to another table...

there is also a not necessarily recommended way to sometimes get around legitimate mutations... `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` - i'll leave it to you to look that up :)

Comment: +1 agreed, except that it's not technically a normalization issue - rather, an issue with the choice of a natural key instead of a surrogate.

Answer (score 1):

you need a Package and two triggers.

the first trigger is an `after update for each row`. It save the id's that was updated in the package global variable.

the second trigger is the `after update trigger (without for each row)`. This trigger can update the parent_id for the id's from the package global variable

Comment: Agree. Remember to think about concurrency issues if two different sessions simultaneously update two different child records of the same parent.